# How to eval PHP when making a template - getting syntax error

Tags: php, templates, eval

I have an html file where I have a syntax like '@echosomething', then I want to load that html file with file_get_contents and replace the template keyword so that it would echo a variable but I am getting a syntax error.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\templating\index.php(9) : eval()'d code on line 1
```

**Here is my html_file.html**

```
<html>
<body>
    @echovalue
</body>
```

**And here is my php code**

```
<?php
    $html_file = file_get_contents( 'html_file.html' );

    $value = "This is a test value!";
    $str = '<?php echo $value; ?>';

    $html_file = str_replace('@echovalue', $str, $html_file);

    eval($html_file);
    echo $html_file;
?>
```

Comment: You're missing a `;` on `$value = "This is a test value!"`

Comment: getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\templating\index.php(9) : eval()'d code on line 1

Comment: How about escaping special characters? `eval(htmlspecialchars($html_file));`

Comment: now I'm getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&', expecting end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\templating\index.php(9) : eval()'d code on line 1

Comment: You would be better off (IMHO) looking into a proper template library rather than trying to make something of your own.

Answer (score 0):

```
$html_file = file_get_contents( 'html_file.html' );

$value = "This is a test value!";
$str = 'return $value;';

echo str_replace('@echovalue', eval($str), $html_file);
echo $html_file;
```

Comment: The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

why not simply

```
$html_file = str_replace('@echovalue', $value, $html_file);
```

?

Comment: how would you do a foreach loop with this?

Comment: i'm not sure if i understand your question correctly, what loop do you need?